# Docker container not updating files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I created a docker container for the first time, my py file had an error in mnTable ( an extra ')')

minTable = [(1300,26), (1000,13.333)), (600, 11.428), (400, 15), (200, 15)]

I removed the ), and tried to re run but it never updated in the container. I have since deleted the container, created new images and new containers, but every single time I get the same 2 errors... Why is this happening and what is the first error?  Also since Im building new images where the extra parentheses error was not even present, why is it still showing up??

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "flask_brevets.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     import acp_times  # Brevet time calculations
web_1  |   File "/app/acp_times.py", line 18
web_1  |     minTable = [(1300,26), (1000,13.333)), (600, 11.428), (400, 15), (200, 15)] 
web_1  |                                         ^
web_1  | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
brevets_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: You really have to provide more information about how you created new images.  What commands did you issue?

Comment: Sure, all i used was docker-compose up command while inside the brevets(app) folder, which contained both the Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml file:                                                                                                   web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/brevets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker compose not building because of an error that has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215640/docker-compose-not-building-because-of-an-error-that-has-been-removed)