# Docker compose not building because of an error that has been removed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I use the command `docker-compose up` in the directory that has the Docker compose Dockerfile, I am hit with the error below. The error was that in acp times app there was an extra brace, which I removed. When I try to run the container again I get the same error message, why is this?

I am new to docker, if any additional info is needed to help solve the problem let me know, I'm not even sure what I am looking for, I followed the docker docks simple instructions. Could it be that something else in my python code is incorrect?

```
Attaching to brevets_web_1 
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "flask_brevets.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     import acp_times  # Brevet time calculations
web_1  |   File "/app/acp_times.py", line 18
web_1  |     minTable = [(1300,26), (1000,13.333)), (600, 11.428), 
(400, 15), (200, 15)] 
web_1  |                                         ^
web_1  | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
brevets_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: you need to rebuild with `docker-compose build`

Answer (score 2):

Like @avigil said you need to rebuild your image in order to update it.

If you want to do it in one command you can type:

> docker-compose up --build

If you really want to be sure that your containers are recreated run the following command:

> docker-compose up --build --force-recreate