# Docker is not accepting proxy api server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, express

i get the following error, when doing a docker-compose up. The app is running but cannot make any api post/get requests. The express server is using port 5000.

> ] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/users/user
>   from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

[image]

Despite having the react proxy set up, the error persists.

**setupProxy.js**

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
//   app.use(proxy('/auth/github', { target: 'http://localhost:3000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/auth/github', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/posts/', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon app.js  --ignore client",
    "build": "echo 'hello build'",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others   \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should the outbound call from the container to `http://localhost:5000/` go?  Should there be a second process running in the same container?

Comment: that just handles the api post request from express. The app runs on localhost:3000, and then uses port 5000 to handle post and get requests from express.

when doing npm start, both the client and express are fired up. ill show package.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to change **localhost:5000** to the name of your service in the **docker-compose.yml**. In this case, you'll need to setup whatever server you have running on **localhost:5000** in the compose file. Remember that your containers are running inside a Docker Network, so, they can't access your **localhost** at the host machine.

In this example, you can see that I needed to set the **PMA_HOST** environment variable to the **db** service instead of a "normal host". In the database configuration, on my source code, I also set up the host to the same **db** service and everything is working just great.

version: '3'

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.0
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  db:
```

This is needed because, every time you run a new container, it will get a different IP into the new Docker Network. In this case, we would always need to check this new IP and set it in our code. Docker solves this by letting us attach the new host to an easy and immutable name, which in compose is the name of the service.

## UPDATE: The network_mode approach

If you already have a service running on your localhost (eg: an API server) and you're using docker for a new service which will interact with that API (eg: a web client UI) but, for some reason, you can't or don't want to setup the API on the **docker-compose.yml** file, you can change the `network_mode` and the `environment HOST`.

In this approach, you'll have to map **the port on the container to an unused port on the host**.

So, lets say you have an API running on `localhost:80` and you're running a node server on docker on port 3000. If you don't have anything running at `localhost:3000`, you could do the following:

```
spa:
   user: ${COMPOSE_UID}:${COMPOSE_GID}
   image: node:10-slim
   working_dir: /home/node/app
   environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
   ports:
      - 3000:3000
   volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
   command: bash -c 'yarn install && yarn run dev'
   network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, let me try out your advice. will let you know how it went.

Comment: i tried to do `ports: - "5000:5000"` it runs the app, but it doest respond on localhost:5000. the site can't be reached.

Comment: When you do "5000:5000", you're mapping the container's 5000 to the localhost 5000. Your code runs inside the Docker Network, so it needs to talk to the container IP (the service name) NOT to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Mapping the port simply allows you to access the container through your host, it doesn't enable containers to talk to each other outside the Docker Network. When your code finds "localhost" inside a container, it translates it to 127.0.0.1 OF THE CONTAINER, not the 127.0.0.1 of the host.

Comment: So, maybe (I'm not sure), if if the API is in the same "app" service that exposes the port 3000 and you change http://localhost:5000/ to http://localhost:3000/, it will reference the container's localhost and the exposed port.

Comment: im still trying to rebuild this docker image, docker is not updating my setupProxy.js

I tried removing the image, and the container and its still not removing it.

Comment: Try to use "docker-compose up --build" to force the image to be rebuilt. Also, if your Express app is a thing apart of your React up, why don't you spin up a separate service only for the Express app and then do as I did with phpMyAdmin and MariaDB? Seems to me this is the best approach, keeping each thing on its on individual container.

Comment: yeah just  i saw that on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215640/docker-compose-not-building-because-of-an-error-that-has-been-removed

so im just waiting for it to finish.

Comment: thank you, i change my ports on setupProxy.js to 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Thank you Matheus for the explanation. I spent hours figuring this out and finally everything works.

Comment: Tried the network_mode and I am getting an error: `"host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings`

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine
EXPOSE 80:8080
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - PORT=8080
      - NODE_ENV=dev
      - ENV_NAME=local  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

**setupProxy.js**

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/auth/github', { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/auth/github', { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/', { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', "secure": false }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/posts/', { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' }))
}
```